# R: LinkedIn scraping using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Using `rvest` package, I am trying to scrape data from my [LinkedIn profile](https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=AAIAAAFqgUsBB2262LNIUKpTcr0cF_ekoX9ZJh0&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile).

These attempts:

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=AAIAAAFqgUsBB2262LNIUKpTcr0cF_ekoX9ZJh0&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile"
li = read_html(url)
html_nodes(li, "#experience-316254584-view span.field-text")
html_nodes(li, xpath='//*[@id="experience-610617015-view"]/p/span/text()')
```

don't find any nodes:

```
#> {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Q: How to return just the text?

```
#> "Quantitative hedge fund manager selection for $650m portfolio of alternative investments"
```

[image: Linkedin profile]

**EDIT:**

LinkedIn has an API, however for some reason, below returns only the first two positions of experience, no other items (like education, projects). Hence the scraping approach.

```
library("Rlinkedin")
auth = inOAuth(application_name, consumer_key, consumer_secret)
getProfile(auth, connections = FALSE, id = NULL) # returns very limited data
```

Comment: `html_text` but LinkedIn also has an API so you really don't have to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things unnecessarily difficult... All you need to do is issue a GET request to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json after obtaining an OAuth 2.0 token from Linkedin. In R, you can do this using [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite):

```
library(jsonlite)
linkedin <- fromJSON('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json')
position <- linkedin$headline
```

You must have the 'r_basicprofile' member permission on your oauth token.

Comment: this is _maybe_ a comment

Comment: I've included the API try, which returns limited data. Hence the scraping.