# Issues logging in to LinkedIn via rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

Starting to experiment with web scraping using the `rvest` package - specifically from websites which require login.

As a starter for 10, I have been trying to log in to LinkedIn, since I found [some apparently simple code to do this](https://gist.github.com/daattali/3868f67e60f477c8c0f0). However, it isn't working for me - I am being redirected to `linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login?errorKey=unexpected_error`. Code is below - any suggestions are much appreciated.

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr)

url <- "https://www.linkedin.com/"
uastring <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
session <- html_session(url, user_agent(uastring))

form <-
  read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("form.login-form") %>% 
  html_form()

filled_form <- set_values(form[[1]],
                          session_key = [email],
                          session_password = [password])
sub <-
  submit_form(session, filled_form)

#> Submitting with 'NULL'

sub

#> <session> https://www.linkedin.com/checkpoint/lg/login?errorKey=unexpected_error
#>   Status: 200
#>   Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
#>   Size:   22647
```

Status is 200, but the login isn't effective. A subsequent `jump_to` gives me the following error:

```r
query <- jump_to(session, [profile url])

query

#> Error in http_statuses[[as.character(status)]]: subscript out of bounds

query <- jump_to(sub, [profile url])

query

#> Error in http_statuses[[as.character(status)]]: subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an acceptable activity under the site's TOS?

Comment: Is this a proof of concept or are you really trying to get data from linkedin? If the latter is the case, this should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457650/r-linkedin-scraping-using-rvest?rq=1

Comment: @JBGruber I already saw this - but it's just for pulling data from your own profile.

Comment: Literally just a proof of concept - trying to pull any data from a website behind a login. Also had issues with Reddit. Login appears to go ok but, when trying to scrape from my notifications (for example) it says I have 2 factor authentication turned on on Reddit (even though I don't).

Comment: I've never used rvest for login in a website. I assumed it wasn't possible anyway. So I can't help with that. What I know is that RSelenium can do these kind of things. But it's even a lot more complicated to handle.